# Not getting the data being pulled from Table and put into JList - just the pointer

Tags: java, sql, swing, jlist

I am wanting to put three columns of data from JAVA DB into a JList. When I run my program I get a list - but they are all pointers for where the data is located! I have tried several things and am at an impasse.

//This is the method from my Class

```
  public void getNames()     
               throws SQLException
     {

   try
   {

          // Create a Statement object for the query.
          Statement stmt =
             conn.createStatement(
                     ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,
                     ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);

          System.out.println("connecting to db for getNames()"); // This is for DEBUGGING

          // Execute the query.
          ResultSet rst = stmt.executeQuery(
                           "SELECT first_name, last_Name, person_id FROM person_info ORDER BY last_name");

          // Get the number of rows
          rst.last();                 // Move to last row
          int numRows = rst.getRow(); // Get row number
          rst.first();                // Move to first row

          // Create an array for the names.
          personData =  new Object[numRows][3];


          // Store the columns in the personData array.
          for (int row = 0; row < numRows; row++)
          {
             for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++)
             {
                personData[row][col] = rst.getObject(col + 1);
             }

             // Go to the next row in the ResultSet.
             rst.next();
          }



          // Close the connection and statement objects.
          conn.close();
          stmt.close();

          System.out.println("Printing" + Arrays.deepToString(personData)); // This is for DEBUGGING
   }
   catch (SQLException ex)
      {
         System.out.println("Hell:" + ex);
      }
   }

   //This is the method to get the above data
   public Object[][] getPersonData()
   {
   System.out.println("getPersonData()" + personData); // This is for DEBUGGING
  return personData;
  }
```

//this is what I am calling the above with and building the Jlist
JList  nameList;

```
private void buildListPanel()
   {
    try
    {
      System.out.println("Building Panel"); // This is for DEBUGGING

     // Create a panel.
     listPanel = new JPanel();

     // Add a titled border to the panel.
     listPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.
     createTitledBorder("Select a Name"));

     // Create an AddressBookManager object.
     pbManager = new AddressBookManager();

     pbManager.getNames();



     // Get the table data.
     Object[][] data = pbManager.getPersonData();  


     System.out.println("build list panel" + Arrays.deepToString(data));    // This is for DEBUGGING

     // Create a JList object to hold the names.
     nameList = new JList<>(data);

     // Set the number of visible rows.
     nameList.setVisibleRowCount(5);

     // Put the JList object in a scroll pane.
     scrollPane = new JScrollPane(nameList);

     // Add the scroll pane to the panel.
     listPanel.add(scrollPane);
     }
  catch(SQLException ex)
    {
     // If something goes wrong with the database, 
     // display a message to the user.
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.toString());
    }
     }
```

> I cannot seem to get a pic of results to show

```
I have a list of names but what appears is a list of these:
       [Ljava.lang.Object;@9225652
       [Ljava.lang.Object;@654f0d9c
       [Ljava.lang.Object;@6a400542
       [Ljava.lang.Object;@658ocfdd
       [Ljava.lang.Object;@7e0b85f9
```

Comment: 1) See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing. 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Thank you Andrew - Long time reader - first time putting my code out there!

Comment: From your code, I suggest you use `JTable` rather than `JList` to display the data retrieved from the database.

Comment: *"Long time reader"* Then you probably have seen earlier comments on posting an MCVE / SSCCE. Any chance we can expect to see one, any time soon?

Comment: Thank you Abra - that did the trick. Appreciate the help!